# why detach partition in postgres is not responding in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

when I am trying to execute below query through Perl script my code is getting unresponsive (not throwing any error only cursor is waiting to execute this query).

```
ALTER TABLE base_table
   DETACH PARTITION part_table;
```

interestingly above query is working fine on the postgres terminal.

what are all the possible scenarios for which i am facing this issue and how it could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There is a concurrent long running transaction holding a lock on the table. Terminate all such transactions, and it will work fine.

Comment: you are right, there is locking in this query can you suggest me how to resolve this lock

Comment: Use `pg_terminate_backend` on the blocking sessions.